# Regular expression in Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying this on apache mod_rewrite using regex.

Check the requesting url.

If it is other than .php or /, rewrite it to authorize.php?token=some_random_token

Requesting url (example token used here):

```
https://example.com/section/video.mp4?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhb
```

Apache mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(section)\/.*$

RewriteRule !^((.\*.php)|(.*\/))$ authorize.php
```

I am stuck here. What should the required regex codes be?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule !^((.\*.php)|(.*\/))$ authorize.php
                 ^
                 Searches for a literal asterisk
```

Aside from the misplaced escape character, you don't need all those parentheses since you're not capturing anything. I expect this should work.

```
RewriteRule !^(.*\.php|.*\/)$ authorize.php [QSA]
```

As for the token, [the QSA flag](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) will move that from your original request to the rewrite.